# Is oscillatory motion possible at constant speed?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, harmonic-oscillator, oscillators

If I do pull-ups without any gradual acceleration like the following graph would it be oscillatory motion?

[image]

I read in a book that the equation of oscillatory motion is $$F=- k x^n$$ where, $n$ = an odd number
Note that the equation implies that the acceleration increases with distance. So, the above graph does not satisfy this equation.
But the definition of Oscillatory motion says: "A to and fro periodic motion", which satisfies the graph. I am confused whether this is an oscillatory motion or not.

Comment: Any change in direction implies an acceleration. The only motion possible in classical physics without acceleration is uniform motion in a straight line.

Comment: @sakurashinken yeah, that's right.. pardon my inability to ask the question correctly. I meant if it will still be an oscillatory motion if the speed was constant

Comment: @Zarif Yes, this is oscillatory motion corresonding to a force equation F = -x^n in the limit for odd n as n tends to infinity.  This is like a object bouncing between two rigid walls.

Comment: @RogerWood how is n tending to infinity related to this?

Comment: „  the equation of oscillatory motion is“ this is not the equation of motion this is the force equation?

Comment: @Zarif You need a force that is as small as possible for $|x|  < 1$ and as large as possible (and in the opposite direction to $x$) for $|x| > 1$. $F=-x^n$ for a large odd value of $n$ meets this profile. In the limit, as $n \rightarrow \infty$, then $F \rightarrow 0$ for $|x| < 1$ and $|F| \rightarrow \infty$ for $|x| > 1$.

Answer (score 1):

Your graph shows that there exists some minima and maxima in the height function $h(t)$. As you probably know at every extremum the functions first derivative must vanish. However since,

- height function is a position,
- its derivative (w.r.t. time) must be a speed (just check the units)

we know that at the extrema the speed is zero. Thus, even if we allow for an infinite large force, the speed is not constant. A *mathematical* work around would be that we consider only certain time intervals $[t_0, t_1]$, $[t_2, t_3]$, where $t_1\ne t_2$.

Answer (score 0):

The peaks of your curve imply infinite energy which is not physically possible. You will reverse direction at a finite acceleration, which will make your triangle wave like curve rounder.

Answer (score 0):

*Periodic motion* is a motion thst repeats itself after some time, *period*, over and over:
$$
h(t+T) = h(t).
$$
*Oscillatory motion* is a perioduc motion that retraces its own trajectory on return, unlike, e.g., rotation.

The motion shown in the graph is oscillatory/periodic (depending on the nature of quantities shown).

The restoring force quoted in the OP is a tyoucal force that leads to an oscillatory motion. There may be other forces of this type, but having more peculiar mathematicsl forms. What is special to the force corresponding to the plit in the OP is that the force is significant (and very big) only near the turning points, where the direction if motion changes, and it is zero elsewhere. One could come up with many mathematical choices for such a force.